# Looking for a way to use 'Sortable' function with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a folder of images which I had hoped to load with php into a list of images that could be moved around with the Sortable jQueryUI function. I ran a basic test of php so I know that php isn't failing, but my code might be faulty for other reasons and my experience with jQueryUI is lacking. Below are the important parts of the code I was hoping to use.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" defer>

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$( "#item-wrap" ).sortable();
$( "#item-wrap" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>

<style>
#item-wrap { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
#item-wrap li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 300px;
height: 300px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
</style>

<ul id="item-wrap">
<?php
  $imagesDir = '/uploads/gallery1/';
  $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
  $imglist = json_encode($images);
  for ($i = 1; $i <= count($imglist); $i++) {
?><li><?php
echo $array[$i];
?></li><?php
  }
</ul>
?>
```

The images fail to display, and no list is created.
Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. would you elaborate on what is actually failing?

Comment: Do you really have /uploads/gallery1/ folder? or do you mean relative path, "uploads/gallery1/" ?

Comment: The images don't load, and the list isn't produced. And in response to Stormherz, the path is relative.

Comment: json_encode converts to a string so `$imglist = json_encode($images);` won't work in your for loop with `count($imglist)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your PHP code block with

```
<?php
    $imagesDir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/uploads/gallery1/';
    $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
?><li><?php
    echo $images[$i];
?></li><?php
```

And please, specify what exactly the problem is - if it's an error - please, attach the message to the question

Comment: The images fail to display, and no list is made.

Comment: @user2126833 Check the $images with var_dump($images); if is is filled with correct names

Comment: var_dump($images) returns empty

Comment: So there is no files found or globbed. "echo $imagesDir;" to see if the path is correct

Comment: Having double checked the path manually, the directory 'uploads' shares a directory with the php file, and the directory 'gallery1' is within the 'uploads' directory. There shouldn't be problems...

Comment: (nevermind, the directory was hidden, and the var_dump works although the images still don't produce)